# MS Chart Rectangular Annotation width in percent and not pixel

Tags: c#, vb.net, annotations, mschart

why is it that the MS chart rectangular annotation width is in percent and not pixel like msdn says it is? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.width(v=vs.110).aspx

This is what msdn says
Gets or sets the width, in pixels, of an annotation.

I'd like to set my width to be pixels like it states. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The my updated answer for a full solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you have found a bug in the documentation! Easy to spot simply by following the link to the [Annotation.Height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) docs..

The dimensions of an `Annotation`, as many others in a `Chart` control, are **indeed given in percentages**. This has the advantage that they quite cleverly  grow and shrink with the `Chart` control just like many other elements.

So if you double the width of the chart you basically double the space for the shown `DataPoints` and if your `Annotation` went over a 1/3 of the width before it will still do that after you have resized the chart..

Which is nice.

But not what you wanted..

So to set the size to a fixed size in pixels you need to do this:

- Calculate the size you want in percentages and set it
- Repeat whenever you resize the chart or its layout

The real problem is the calculation: If you look at the `Chart.ClientSize` you get the size in pixels and to get n pixels you need to do something like this:

```
float WidthInPercent = 100f * n / Chart.ClientSize.width;
```

This however does not take into account the various elements your `Chart` probably has : The `Size` of an `Annotation` is **not** really calculated as **direct percentages** of the Chart's size.

Instead it is calulated as percentages of the `InnerPlotPosition` of the `ChartArea CA`.

`InnerPlotPosition` by default is set to `Auto` so accessing its values, e.g. `CA.InnerPlotPosition.Width` will return `0f`; but you **can** get at the (current!!) values by doing this:

```
RectangleF IPP = CA.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
```

The same goes for the `Size/Position` of the `ChartArea` itself:

```
RectangleF CAP = CA.Position.ToRectangleF();
```

Now you can combine these percentages with the (**current!**) `Chart.ClientSize` to find out which percentage you need to achieve a certain pixel size..

Note that these values will **change when resizing** because the outer extras, like `Legend` and `Axis` and `Labels` etc. will not resize, so their relative sizes will grow or shink in relation to their containing elements..

So **you need to recalculate** upon each `Resize` event, or, better: write a  function to do it for you which you can call wheneber needed..

The result is an `Annotation` that will (pretty much, due to rounding) maintain its size, no matter how you resize the `Chart`..

**Here are some helpful functions:**

This one returns the **current**  `ClientRectangle` of a `ChartArea` in pixels

```
RectangleF ChartAreaClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF CAR = CA.Position.ToRectangleF();
    float pw = chart.ClientSize.Width / 100f;
    float ph = chart.ClientSize.Height / 100f;
    return new RectangleF(pw * CAR.X, ph * CAR.Y, pw * CAR.Width, ph * CAR.Height);
}
```

This one is similar and  returns the current  `ClientRectangle` of a `ChartArea's InnerplotPosition` in pixels:

```
RectangleF InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF IPP = CA.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
    RectangleF CArp = ChartAreaClientRectangle(chart, CA);

    float pw = CArp.Width / 100f;
    float ph = CArp.Height / 100f;

    return new RectangleF(CArp.X + pw * IPP.X, CArp.Y + ph * IPP.Y, 
                            pw * IPP.Width, ph * IPP.Height);
}
```

Finally one that converts a size in pixels to one in percentages, again valid only currently, i.e. until the next changes in size or layout..:

```
SizeF Pixels2Percent( ChartArea CA, int w, int h)
{
    RectangleF IPPR = InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, CA);

    float pw = 100f * w / IPPR.Width ;
    float ph = 100f * h / IPPR.Height ;

    return new SizeF(pw, ph);
}
```

Lets have a look at the result before and after some resizing:

[image][image]

As you can see the size stay the same.

Also note the colored rectangles I draw in the `Paint` event to demostrate the new functions!

Here is the `Paint` event:

```
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Violet, 
               Rectangle.Round(ChartAreaClientRectangle(chart1, CA)));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LimeGreen, 
               Rectangle.Round(InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, CA)));
}
```

Here is the `Resize` event:

```
private void chart1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sizeAnn(ra, new Size(24, 36));
}
```

And here the sizing function:

```
void sizeAnn(RectangleAnnotation ra, Size sz)
{
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    SizeF pixelPercent = Pixels2Percent(CA, sz.Width, sz.Height);
    ra.Width = pixelPercent.Width;
    ra.Height = pixelPercent.Height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we cannot set it in % or px as the property value is set to double.
Secondly, pixle = H multiplied by W. but you are only setting the width of chart then how can you set it in pixle? It fundamentally not possible. I hope you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP wanted to set the width in pixels, but in case some people (like me) want to set the width neither in pixels nor in %, but according to the actual values, just set :

```
annotation.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = False
annotation.Width = whatEverValue
```