# How to drag a DataPoint and move it in a Chart control

Tags: c#, charts, mousemove, datapoint

I want to be able to grab a datapoint drawn in a chart and  to move it and change its position by dragging it over the chart control.

How can I ..

1. ..grab the specific series point (series name ="My Series")
2. When released the series point should change its position/ values

It's like making series points movable with drag event.

Here the color dots (points) should be able to move:

[image]

There are some charts like devExpress chart which perform this task but I want to do it in normal MS chart.

Comment: Do you really want to move a datapoint (ie change its x- and/ or y-value) or do you want to move (i.e. scroll) the series?

Comment: @TaW : I have a series( of type point) with different points on it which is plot by a user using certain dialog input . So I want to move the datapoint so that the position of other point does not change only the position of the particular point that is Dragged should change.      
Also after the drag is over the point should fix in new position.

Thanks for the reply I really need to do this.

Comment: OK, I see. So the dragging should chnge both x- and y-values. Interesting idea! The 1st problem is in converting to and from pixels and data values. Can you tell me what the data values are ? DataType? - The 2nd the interactivity. I'll play around with it later today ;-)

Comment: the data types of the point are double . I will post a picture in my question to see what need to be dragged. Thanks

Comment: So? The values can be double without changing the code!

Comment: I have had a look at your image. There should not be a problem with my solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moving a `DataPoint` is not a built-in feature of the `Chart` control. We need to code it..

The problem with interacting with a Chart by mouse is that there are **not one but three** coordinate systems at work in a `Chart`:

- The chart elements, like a `Legend` or an `Annotation` are measured in percentages of the respective containers. Those data make up an `ElementPosition` and usually go from `0-100%`.
- The Mouse coordinates and all graphics drawn in one of the three `Paint` events, all work in  pixels; they go from `0-Chart.ClientSize.Width/Height`.
- The `DataPoints` have an x-value and one (or more) y-values(s). Those are doubles and they can go from and to anywhere you set them to.

For our task we need to convert between **mouse pixels** and **data values**.

**DO see the Update below!**

[image][image]

There are several ways to do this, but I think this is the cleanest:

First we create a few class level variables that hold references to the targets:

```
// variables holding moveable parts:
ChartArea ca_ = null;
Series s_ = null;
DataPoint dp_ = null;
bool synched = false;
```

When we set up the chart we fill some of them:

```
ca_ = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
s_ = chart1.Series[0];
```

Next we need two helper functions. They do the 1st conversion between pixels and data values:

```
    // two helper functions:
    void SyncAllPoints(ChartArea ca, Series s)
    {
        foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points) SyncAPoint(ca, s, dp);
        synched = true;
    }

    void SyncAPoint(ChartArea ca, Series s, DataPoint dp)
    {
        float mh = dp.MarkerSize / 2f;
        float px = (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
        float py = (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);
        dp.Tag = (new RectangleF(px - mh, py - mh, dp.MarkerSize, dp.MarkerSize));
    }
```

Note that I chose to use the `Tag` of each `DataPoints` to hold a `RectangleF` that has the clientRectangle of the `DataPoint`'s Marker.

These rectangles will **change** whenever the chart is **resized** or other changes in the Layout, like sizing of a Legend etc.. have happend, so we need to re-synch them each time! And, of course you need to initially set them whenever you add a `DataPoint`!

Here is the `Resize` event:

```
private void chart1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    synched = false;
}
```

The actual refreshing of the rectangles is being triggered from the `PrePaint` event:

```
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if ( !synched) SyncAllPoints(ca_, s_);
}
```

Note that calling the `ValueToPixelPosition` is **not always valid**! If you call it at the wrong time it will return null.. We are calling it from the `PrePaint` event, which is fine. The flag will help keeping things efficient.

Now for the **actual moving of a point**: As usual we need to code the three mouse events:

In the `MouseDown` we loop over the `Points` collection until we find one with a `Tag` that contains the mouse position. Then we store it and change its Color..:

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataPoint dp in s_.Points)
        if (((RectangleF)dp.Tag).Contains(e.Location))
        {
            dp.Color = Color.Orange;
            dp_ = dp;
            break;
        }
}
```

In the `MouseMove` we do the **reverse calculation** and set the values of our point; note that we also synch its new position and trigger the `Chart` to refresh the display:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left) && dp_ != null)
    {
        float mh = dp_.MarkerSize / 2f;
        double vx = ca_.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X);
        double vy = ca_.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y);

        dp_.SetValueXY(vx, vy);
        SyncAPoint(ca_, s_, dp_);
        chart1.Invalidate();
    }
   else
   {
       Cursor = Cursors.Default;
       foreach (DataPoint dp in s_.Points)
          if (((RectangleF)dp.Tag).Contains(e.Location))
          {
             Cursor = Cursors.Hand; break;
          }
   }
}
```

Finally we clean up in the `MouseUp` event:

```
    private void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dp_ != null)
        {
            dp_.Color = s_.Color;
            dp_ = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I have set up my chart:

```
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
S1.MarkerSize = 8;
S1.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
S1.Points.AddXY(2, 7);
S1.Points.AddXY(3, 2);
S1.Points.AddXY(4, 9);
S1.Points.AddXY(5, 19);
S1.Points.AddXY(6, 9);

S1.ToolTip = "(#VALX{0.##} / #VALY{0.##})";

S1.Color = Color.SeaGreen;

CA.AxisX.Minimum = S1.Points.Select(x => x.XValue).Min();
CA.AxisX.Maximum = S1.Points.Select(x => x.XValue).Max() + 1;
CA.AxisY.Minimum = S1.Points.Select(x => x.YValues[0]).Min();
CA.AxisY.Maximum = S1.Points.Select(x => x.YValues[0]).Max() + 1;
CA.AxisX.Interval = 1;
CA.AxisY.Interval = 1;

ca_ = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
s_ = chart1.Series[0];
```

Note that I have set both the `Minima` and `Maxima` as well as the `Intervals` for both `Axes`. This stops the `Chart` from running wild with its automatic display of `Labels`, `GridLines`, `TickMarks` etc..

Also note that this will work with any `DataType` for X- and YValues. Only the `Tooltip` formatting will have to be adapted..

Final note: To prevent the users from moving a `DataPoint` off the `ChartArea` you can add this check into the `if-clause` of the `MouseMove` event:

```
  RectangleF ippRect = InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, ca_);
  if (!ippRect.Contains(e.Location) ) return;
```

For the `InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle` function [see here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262#36497262)

**Update:**

On revisiting the code I wonder why I didn't choose a simpler way:

```
DataPoint curPoint = null;

private void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    curPoint = null;
}

private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
        Axis ay = ca.AxisY;

        HitTestResult hit = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hit.PointIndex >= 0) curPoint = hit.Series.Points[hit.PointIndex];

        if (curPoint != null)
        {
            Series s = hit.Series;
            double dx = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
            double dy = ay.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);

            curPoint.XValue = dx;
            curPoint.YValues[0] = dy;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Comment: Ok thanks I am new to stack overflow and I did not know that I will do it now . Just curious can we do the same solution using drag and drop event like dragEnter ,dragOver and dragLeave. Your solution works fine just curious to see if its possible. :)

Comment: I don't think so. You could start it but can't really know which point you are one __and__ D&D will not really care about the precise position you drop, so you can't really put the point to a certain position either.. To add pixel precision to D&D wouln make it necessary to code the mouseevents anyway and it wouldn't be easy, since D&D basically filters them out. -  The other options I mentioned would involve using `Annotations` but it would be more expensive plus I couldn't get it to work or doing the calculations differently but I didn't even try that since this solution works so nicely..

Comment: yes had the same problem trying to do it with D&D as you mention .So I had to go with your solution. Thanks for the answer , and also thanks for answering my previous questions :)

Answer (score 1):

download **Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls**

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61

Check this:

**Chart Features -> Interactive Charting -> Selection -> Changing Values by dragging**