# Live Editable Graph C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, visual-studio-2015

I want a graph that has the same working of a fan curve control graph you can see in apps like MSI Afterburner or EVGA Precision.

[image: EVGA Precision]

In simple words, live editable graph in which I can move points around and the graph to return values of the points.

This might be something that has been asked before but I cannot word a search query as I dont know what do we call these types of graph.

Regards and Merry Christmas!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - So what is your question? I suggest using the MSChart control.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that. Ill add it. It's **WinForm** btw.

Comment: @TaW can I change point coordinates by dragging them in the graph in MSChart?

Comment: You can code it. See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690301/how-to-drag-a-datapoint-and-move-it-in-a-chart-control/36715261?s=1|1.4225#36715261)

Comment: @TaW would you be able to point me to a good tutorial for MSChart that is for 2015 or 2013. I can only find 2008 and 2003 versions.

Comment: There has been no change in the Control itself that I am aware of. The only changes are the new LINQ extension methods which I believe came in vs2008 to c# (c#3) and which can be applied to the chart's various collections as well; so it is rather simple to grab say the minimum value from a points collection etc.. - In fact I don't know of any really good and in depth tutorial. Maybe, if enough folks are interested [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mschart/commit) will create one..