# Charting - Set grid above the graph

Tags: c#, charts

I'm working with the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` library of C# in Visual Studio.
Creating the graphs themselves is no problem, however, since I'm using `SeriesChartType.StackedArea100` for my serieses (which always fills the vertical graph space 100%), the grid (X & Y) is completely covered by the graphs.

However, I want the X-grid to be above the graphs, so it's easier to see which point belongs to what.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You could make the DataPoints color semi-transparent. Or paint a Grid in the PostPaint event.

Comment: You can show the data point values by tooltip on chart.

Comment: @TaW: That sounds good, do you have an approach for drawing a Grid myself with that event? The chart is `CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true`, so users can select ranges of it, zoom in and scroll along. How would I get started drawing the right amount of lines and the furthermore on the appropriate X-coordinates? Is there anything, that saves me the work of implementing it fully by myself?
@sowjanyaattaluri: Thanks I'm already doing that, but I'm using >20 serieses, so it becomes tedious to look up the tooltips every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gridlines` are always drawn under the `DataPoints`.

One option is to make the `Colors` of the `DataPoints` semi-transparent.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
chart1.ApplyPaletteColors();  // necessary to access the original colors
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    foreach (Series s in chart1.Series) s.Color = Color.FromArgb(192, s.Color);
}
```

You can raise alpha to 224 and still see the lines.

Or you could **owner-draw** `GridLines` in one of the `xxxPaint` events; but that of course is a little more complicated. OK, a lot more..

The drawing itself is regular GDI+ drawing with `DrawLine` calls in two loops.

But to get the loops and the coordinates right you need to :

- Make sure you know/control the `Minimum`, `Maximum` & `Interval` for the axes. If they are not set but still on their auto-values you need to find a way to get at them.
- know the Rectangle of the `InnerPlotPosition` in pixels(!). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262?s=3|0.0000#36497262) for two functions that will help you !

Here is an example:

[image]

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked) return;

    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    RectangleF ipar = InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, ca);
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    Color gc = ax.MajorGrid.LineColor;
    Pen pen = new Pen(gc); 
    double ix = ax.Interval == 0 ? 1 : ax.Interval;  // best make sure to set..
    double iy = ay.Interval == 0 ? 50 : ay.Interval; // ..the intervals!

    for (double vx = ax.Minimum; vx <= ax.Maximum; vx+= ix)
    {
        int x = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(vx) + 1;
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, ipar.Top, x, ipar.Bottom);
    }

    for (double vy = ay.Minimum; vy <= ay.Maximum; vy += iy)
    {
        int y = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(vy) + 1;
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, ipar.Left, y, ipar.Right, y);
    }
    pen.Dispose();
}
```

You should disable the `GridLines` and maybe even make the the `Axes` transparent:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: Thank you for that!
I guess drawing the GridLines is done via standard Pens and Brushes? If I fail to implement it, I'll resort to using colors with reduced opacity.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you so much for all your effort, now the question is thoroughly solved in every aspect.