# MSChart drag chart in order to scroll chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

Is there any way I can click on a MSChart and drag it left/right in order to scroll the chart to the right/left.
The idea is to drag the chart instead of dragging the chart's scroll bar.
The reason I'm not simply using the scroll bar is because I was asked to add this feature (bosses and their demands..).
Btw, I'm using C# and winforms.
Hope I was clear enough.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.

One issue is that you can't use the normal zooming/scrolling mechanism as this itself  works by dragging over the chart.

Instead pass it by and code two mouseevents and use the `Axis.PixelPositionToValue` function to access the data values.

First we store the data value of the clicked location:

```
double mDown = double.NaN;

private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    mDown = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X);
}
```

Then we calculate the old range how far the `Axis.Minimum` has moved and adapt `Minimum` and `Maximum`:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)) return;
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    double range = ax.Maximum - ax.Minimum;
    double xv = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X);
    ax.Minimum -= xv - mDown;
    ax.Maximum = ax.Minimum + range;
}
```

You will want to add a few checks to prevent dragging too far left or right..

Note that the code assumes that you have set `Minimum` and `Maximum`!

Also note that you will want to take control over the format of the x-axis labels so they don't make the chart jump around by having lot of fractional digits.

Or, depending on your data, you may want to set the step to a multiple of some value, suitable for your interval or in my case simply to `ints`:

```
ax.Minimum -= (int)(xv - mDown) ;
```

If you need to have the scrollbars visible you can still use the above code; but you need to replace this

```
ax.Minimum -= (int)(xv - mDown);
ax.Maximum = ax.Minimum + range;
```

by this:

```
double oldPos = ax.ScaleView.Position;
ax.ScaleView.Position -= (xv - mDown);
```

However this **does** interfer with the normal scolling. You can insert checks to make sure you are not hitting the scrollbar like this:

```
RectangleF ipar = InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, chart1.ChartAreas[0]);
if (ipar.Contains(e.Location))
{
  ..
  ..
```

..but it still acts up here. So **either or** seems to work best.

The `InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle` is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262#36497262).