# Bar Chart with issue (Forms MC Chart)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, charts, stackedbarseries

I want to draw 52 Bar series in a Bar chart to represent weeks in a year. However, there seems to be an issue with the chart, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

I have 2 series that I draw with label, x value,y value. E.g.:

```
chart1.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY("W1", 0, 168);
chart1.Series["Missing"].Points.AddXY("W1", 0, 0);
```

However there seems to be a difference between the bar series (sometines thicker sometimes smiller), even though I create them with the same method:

```
  var series = new Series
        {
            Name = seriesName,
            ChartArea = chartAreaName,
            Color = color,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar,
            XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto,
            YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto,
            SmartLabelStyle = new SmartLabelStyle
            {
                AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes,
                MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Right,
                IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false
            }
        };
```

How can I prevent this form happening?

Comment: What is your ChartType? For a Bar chart the code doesn't run as you can't add more than 1 y-value. Also: Never add x-values as strings!!

Comment: I simply set ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar,

Answer (score 0):

The effect is a rounding effect that results from having such a large number of bars.

To avoid it you would have to make sure the `InnerPlotPosition.Height`'s number of pixels is divisible by 52.

There is an anti-aliasing property ..:

```
chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
```

..but it already is set to `All` by default.

Calculating the nearest size is not as simple as one would wish. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262#36497262) for methods that calculate the `InnerPlotPosition` and you can use `ToRectangleF();` to enforce calculating number while the chart is still using automatic values.

But since those numbers are in percent and the other elements, i.e. the title, legend and x-axis with its labels all weigh in, reversing the calculation to find a number that works is not only hard, it will also fail with each resizing of the `Chart`. And, obviously, when adding more points..

If you can live without resizing you can find a suitable `chart.Size` by trial and error, e.g. by growing it in a button click: `chart.Height += 1;`

But imo the best solution is to **reduce** the Bars' **width** in a controlled way yourself, maybe like this:

```
  yourSeries.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "3");
```

The efect will still hapen, but with larger gaps it won't be as noticeable.